# R convert exponent (read by R as string) into simple number

Tags: r, exponent

I read a CSV file into R with the following command:

```
myfile <- read.csv('C:/Users/myfilepath.csv', sep=',', header = F)
```

With this I get a nice data frame looking a little like this:

```
year / Variable1 /             Variable2 / etc.
1958 / 1.42547014192473E-08 / 3.06399766669684E-10 / etc.
1959 / 2.05022315791225E-09 / 8.80152568089836E-08 / etc.
1960 / etc. ....                  ....
```

However, R seems to treat the letter E for exponents as string. So I need to convert these first into a simple number before I can analyze the data. The data set has 50 rows and 12 columns.

I tried `as.numeric` but get the error message

> Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Any ideas?

Comment: `apply(myfile[.-1], 2, as.numeric)`?

Comment: The following works: as.numeric("3.06399766669684E-10").

Comment: You need to convert individual columns to numeric, not the whole data.frame at once. If it is all in fact numeric (`year` is probably integer, if it matters), you can do it with `sapply(myfile, as.numeric)`

Comment: @Sotos your solution gets rid of the year column but the the exponents remain. Thanks though

Comment: @Imo I am sure your solution works it is just not very practicable doing that 20x50x24 =100'960 times. That is at least how many observations I am going to have. Thanks for editing my post though and making it look nice.

Comment: @alistaire indeed year matters. :-) Tried your solution. same problem as with Sotos solution. Guess it is either the way I import data or as.numeric function.

Comment: It's not really a matter of whether the exponents are there (that's a printing thing, which you can get around with `format(... , scientific = FALSE)`), it's a matter of whether your data is stored character or numeric, which determines what you can do with it. If you want to keep `year` as integer, just overwrite the rest: `myfile[, -1] <- sapply(myfile[, -1], as.numeric)`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can format the DF using: 
   format(myfile,scientific=FALSE)
2. You can use "options("scipen"=100)" before you read the file.

If you see there is tailing zeros, then I will suggest tou to check the csv file before import.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. No 1 went through but exponents persist. No 2 produced a series of error messages when used with read.csv or read.table.

Answer (score 0):

The answers by Soto and Alistair work if the cells in the csv that is imported are formatted as 'scientific'. Otherwise it doesn't. Thanks guys!

Code used:

```
mydata<- read.csv('C:/Users/mydata.csv', sep=',', na.strings=c("", "NA"), header = F)
mydata <- sapply(mydata, as.numeric)
```

Comment: Your answer should also answer the question, not only give attribution to commenters.